# How to bind command and contexrt from UserControl to MainView UWP MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, datacontext

There is a form in which the label is located, as well as a user control wrapped in a button. I need to change the text in the TextBlock by clicking the button in the user control. I didn't use any MVVM frameworks.
Main XAML:

```
    <Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="553*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="197*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:ControlView Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding UserText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    
</Grid>
```

User Conrol Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="300" Height="100" FontSize="50" Command="{Binding}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Print chart" />
</Grid>
```

Main VM:

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        
        SetText = new RelayCommand(SetUserText);
    }

    public ICommand SetText { get; set; }

    public string UserText { get; set; }

    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void SetUserText()
    {
        UserText = "Hello World!";
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(UserText ));
    }

    
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

And I create an empty user control VN:

```
public class ControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    // And what should I do here?
}
```

So how to correctly implement commands from user control to main view, f.e SetText property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is there is the use of the `ControlViewModel`. `UserControls` such as `ControlView` should generally speaking not set their own `DataContext` to some specialized view model but rather inherit the `DataContext` from their parent element.

Assuming you let the control inherit the `DataContext`, you could add a dependency property to it and bind the command to this one:

```
<local:ControlView YourCommand="{Binding SetText}" />
```

**ControlView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl ... Name="uc">
    <Button Command="{Binding YourCommand, ElementName=uc}" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer is very helpful!